# xlsxwriter split one excel to several excels with original format and formula

Tags: split, xlsxwriter

I have one excel with a lot of information, need to split to many excels based on one column.
And need to keep all the format and calculation formula in the separated excels:

Sample as below:

[image]

Comment: XlsxWriter can't read or modify files. You will need to look at openpyxl or Pandas (using openpyxl).

Comment: how to used openpyxl to realize

Answer (score 1):

This is tagged as xlsxwriter, but is not possible using xlsxwriter since copying styles or reading xlsx files just isn't going to work. So here's a solution using openpyxl:

First you need to group all the rows by your value with each cell's styling. You'll just need to write each group to a new excel. Something like:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'Book1.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

groupedRows = {}

#Group rows by 3rd column
for row_num, row in enumerate(sheet):
    rowData = [[cell.value, cell.style] for cell in row]
    if row_num != 0:
        if groupedRows.get(row[2].value, False):
            groupedRows[row[2].value].append(rowData)
        else:
            groupedRows[row[2].value] = [header]
            groupedRows[row[2].value].append(rowData)
    else:
        header = rowData
            

#Write each group to a sheet
wb = Workbook()
dest_filename = 'test.xlsx'
for group, rows in groupedRows.items():
    out_sheet = wb.create_sheet(title=group)
    for row_num, row in enumerate(rows):
        for col_num, col in enumerate(row):
            c = out_sheet.cell(row_num+1, col_num+1, col[0])
            c.style = col[1]
            

wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

I've just tested this with Book1.xlsx looking like:

[image: Book1.xlsx]

Which resulted in:

[image: test condition1]

and

[image]

**However**!

> And need to keep all the format and calculation formula in the
> separated excels

Formulas will not work. They will be copied verbatim which means they'll be referencing the previous cell locations. [That may be possible using the formulae translation tools in openpyx](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formula.html#translating-formulae-from-one-location-to-another)l.